# Cannot call java class from groovy script in SoapUI

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I try run [this](http://dbunit.wikidot.com/demoimportexport) from groovy script in SoapUI. I build a jar file containing this code and put that jar file in the /bin/ext directory.
But after run I see this:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script4.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class
>   net.dbunit.dbunittest.DBUnitTest @ line 1, column 1. import
>   net.dbunit.dbunittest.DBUnitTest ^
>   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class
>   net.dbunit.dbunittest.DBUnitTest @ line 1, column 1. at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1145)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$10.call(CompilationUnit.java:632)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:523)
>   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
>   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
>   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:152)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:97)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:154)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:277)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 1 error

I re-start SoapUI, but it's not work.

Answer (score 2):

The script you packaged into a jar depends on `net.dbunit.dbunittest.DBUnitTest`. You need to provide these dependencies as well as possible transistive dependencies.